# Service blocks intents with BOOT_COMPLETED action

Tags: android, bootcompleted

While booting, my Presitio phone starts some system service which blocks intents with BOOT_COMPLETED action. Logcat contains a lot of messages like

> I/ActivityManagerAR(  518): remove Intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
> receiver=ResolveInfo{26aaaec8 com.idea.backup.smscontacts/.Receiver
> m=0x108000} for User App

How could I understand, which service makes these messages?

**Update.**
Well, it seems some manufacturer's component locks BOOT_COMPLETED. Executing

> am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.company.app

(package name here just for example), goes to messages

> D/ActivityManager(  518): send broadcast: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED, **skip package: com.company.app**
>
> D/BroadcastQueue(  518): Add broadcastBroadcastRecord{3c6dabd4 u0 android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED} into (background/order), now header = BroadcastRecord{3c6dabd4 u0 android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED}, size = 1
>
> D/BroadcastQueue(  518): Finished with ordered broadcast BroadcastRecord{3c6dabd4 u0 android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED}, [background], remain = 0

This is known problem, autostart not works on some models. There are related posts on SO:

[Android BOOT_COMPLETED event not starting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855072/android-boot-completed-event-not-starting-service)

[Autostart (BOOT_COMPLETED) does not work on the Nomi tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945483/autostart-boot-completed-does-not-work-on-the-nomi-tablet)

*I suppose this behavior has relation to [Android Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) concept.*

So the actual problem is how to locate and disable that component.

Answer (score -1):

The log message seems to be generated (could be fake though) from `ActivityManager` with PID=518 and the receiver removed was from `com.idea.backup.smscontacts`.